# Change directory of xlsx file in s3 bucket using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

The goal of my code is to change the directory of a file every 24 hours (because every day a new one is created with another lambda function). I want to get the current file from my s3 bucket and write it to another directory in the same s3 bucket. Currently, this line of the code does not work: `s3.put_object(Body=response, Bucket=bucket, Key=fileout)` and I get this error: `"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Body,  "errorType": "ParamValidationError"`  What does the error mean and what is needed in order to be able to store the response in the history directory?

```py
import boto3
import json
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = "some-bucket"
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file='latest/some_file.xlsx'
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)
    fileout = 'history/some_file.xlsx'
    s3.put_object(Body=response, Bucket=bucket, Key=fileout)   
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(data),
    }
```

Comment: Just an assumption. Check the "response" (print it out or set a breakpoint if you can).

 This is probably not only the document but also its meta data. You probably are getting a json object ?

Is the content of the document in body of response ? 
what does this command prints ? 


 print(response['Body'].read())


You cant just upload a json to s3, make a file from it first :)

Answer (score 1):

The response variable in your code stores more than just the actual xlsx file. You should get the body from the response and pass it to the put object method.

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)['Body']
```

Comment: You were correct. Thank you. However, now I still cannot write the file to s3 since I get the following error: StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'tell

Comment: Try with response.read() on the Body input, so it gets all at once.